# Why Constraint Layout is not displaying properly?

Tags: xml, android-layout

I am using constraint layout to create no item page. But in android design view the layout is displaying fine. But when I run the app in a device the layout is not displaying properly.

**I want to show the  no Item message in the middle as below**

[image]

**But in the device, no item message is not showing in the centre**

[image]

**Xml**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:visibility="gone"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/warning_img"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:src="@drawable/warning"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/warning_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/warning_img"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
android:text="no item found!"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/warning_img"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/warning_img" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressbar"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:visibility="gone"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_view"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, it should be working just fine. Nevertheless, you could try using a `Guideline` to center your elements.

Like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/warning_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/warning_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warning_img"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="no item found!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

This will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But It was my mistake. After hours of trial, I have found my mistake, there was a nested layout and the parent layout height was wrap content.